# Three.js, group rotation

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I have two box geometries:

```
var box;
loader.load( 'img/plytos.jpg', function ( texture ){
var boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(7,0.5,0.5);
var boxMaterial =  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: texture, overdraw: 0.5 });
box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, boxMaterial);
box.castShadow = true;

box.position.x=15;
box.position.y=5;
box.position.z=2.7; 
group.add(box);


var box;
loader.load( 'img/plytos.jpg', function ( texture ){
var boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(7,7,0.5);
var boxMaterial =  new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: texture, overdraw: 0.5 });
box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, boxMaterial);
box.castShadow = true;

box.position.x=15;
box.position.y=5;
box.position.z=2.7; 
group.add(box);
```

Both of them are in one group which is spinning around:

```
group.rotation.y += ctrl.groupStep;
```

So let's say I want them to keep spinning like this, because there are more different objects in a same group, but I also would like these two box geometries to rotate while they're spinning.
So I tried to add this line next to group.rotation:

```
box.rotation.z += 0.02;
```

However only one box is rotating.

How to make both of them rotate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I achieved wanted results.
I renamed second box to box2.